# MySQL: Select all that only have two rows, with specific values?

Tags: mysql

I would like to grab all the users that ONLY have two roles, which are 1 and 4.

One user role is stored like this:

```
user_id role_id
54321   1
54321   4
54322   1
54323   1
```

How can i make a query, that grabs the user_id 54321, because it Only have two roles and these two are 1 and 4?

I can use WHERE role_id IN (1, 4) but this will also grab users that have other roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I like to solve these with `group by` and `having` because that is the most general approach:

```
select user_id
from user_roles ur
group by user_id
having sum(role_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(role_id = 4) > 0 and
       sum(role_id not in (1, 4)) = 0;
```

The `having` clause has three conditions.  The first counts the number of times that role is 1, and the `user_id` passes if there is at least one such role.  The second does the same for 4.  The last checks that there are no other values.

I like this structure because it is flexible.  If the condition were 1 and 4 and others are allowed, you would just drop the third clause.  If the condition were 1 or 4 and no others, then it would look like:

```
having (sum(role_id = 1) > 0 or
        sum(role_id = 4) > 0
       ) and
       sum(role_id not in (1, 4)) = 0;
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you for introducing me for this solution

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE role_id IN (1, 4) GROUP BY user_ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2
```

http://gregorulm.com/relational-division-in-sql-the-easy-way/

Comment: I did this: "SELECT users.id FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2" - did not work

Comment: WHERE role_id I think and isnt that user_id and not user.id?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand?

Comment: SELECT users.user_id FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.user_id = roles_users.user_id WHERE role_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY users.user_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2

Comment: It is users.id not users.user_id, this was just my example in the question. Still not working with HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u3.user_id
FROM t u1, t u2, t u3
WHERE u1.role_id = 1 AND u2.role_id = 4
 AND u3.user_id = u1.user_id 
 AND u2.user_id = u1.user_id
GROUP BY u3.user_id HAVING COUNT(u3.role_id) = 2;
```